# How to get to openproject after installation

Tags: openproject

This is a **very** basic question, but I am totally new to openproject so be patient. I have installed openproject in Ubuntu 22.04 following [these instructions](https://www.openproject.org/docs/installation-and-operations/installation/packaged/#ubuntu-2204). I entered `openproject.dell-xps.com` as qualified domain name. Everything seems to have worked fine, but now I am lost at sea: how do I get to openproject on my computer? When I go to openproject.dell-xps.com I land on an Apache 2 Ubuntu webpage.